# Exclude attributes from generating variations, but show all of them on the product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make a change on how my products are being showed up on the product page.

I have the product with 2 types of attributes: size and color. Size has 6 options and Color has 20 options. When combined it generates 120 variations for the product. The price is fixed for every 120 variations.

Is there a way to generate only 6 variations with the Size attribute, but on the product page to show both Size and Color attributes?

In Woocommerce if I do not generate all the variations possible from the attributes it will not show simply on the product page.

For example if I generate 6 variations with the Size attributes, on the product page The Size options will be visible, but the Color options will not be visible.

I want to generate less variations for every product because when you have 120 variations for 1 product it slows down the performance of the website because of more data to process.

Comment: This can be done easily for sure, but you will have a problem with the stock management... Also, if you use a different image for each color is better to set the variations based on color and leave on each color variation the attribute size as "Any size" like in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGhnz.png). For auto generating variations on the color attribute, first set only on the variable product "color" attribute as "Used for variations". Then auto generate your variations. After set Size attribute as "Used for variations". On all variations "size" attribute is set as "Any size".

Comment: I do not use a different image for each color.

Comment: Then if you don't manage stock for each variation and don't use different image for each color and if there are no differences like price or others, you can even only set one variation for all which attribute size will be set as "Any size" and attribute color will be set as "Any color".

Comment: Of course it works :D … Maybe I should answer this question for the community.